# Refactor string .gsub

Tags: ruby, regex

As not expert in regular expressions, i think the next code can be optimized. I would appreciate any help.

```
line = ".ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-s { background-position: -176px -3px; }"

line.gsub!(/-?\d+px/) do |match|
  match.gsub(/-?\d+/) do |i|
    i.to_i + 4
  end
end

#=> ".ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-s { background-position: -172px 1px; }"
```

Comment: "i think the next code can be optimized" is a dead giveaway that this should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
line.gsub(/-?\d+(?=px)/){|s| s.to_i+4}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need any lookahead or grouping for this one:

```
line.gsub(/-?\d+px/){|s| "#{s.to_i+4}px"}
#=> ".ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-s { background-position: -172px 1px; }"
```

Comment: Tranks. it works too. In this case replacing with "(N)px", but in sawa's just numbers.